What is the sefer hasichos ? How is it different from likkutei sichos?
What is sefer hasichos? I know what toras menachem is, what likkutei sichos is, but what's sefer hasichos? How is it different from likkutei sichos?

Likkutei Sichos is a set of 39 volumes which were compiled from 1950 until 1992.
Likkutei Sichos was written by a team of scholars including but not limited to Rabbi Yoel Kahn Rabbi Nachman Shapiro Rabbi Leibel Shapiro and others.
The contents are based off the talks of the Lubavitcher Rebbe, combining various talks (Sichos), adding sources and footnotes and creating a finished discourse on each Parsha and Holiday.
These were then looked over by the Rebbe and approved after which they would come out every week in booklet form and then they would be bound into a volume sometimes consisting of up to 4 or 5 discourses per parsha and holiday.
Not every talk that the Rebbe gave is included in Likkutei Sichos, rather they are select talks chosen by the Rebbe and his team of scholars.
Sefer Hasichos is all the talks from the years 1987 until 1992 that were given over by the Rebbe.
These were often translated from the original Yiddish to Hebrew.
Both likkutei Sichos and Sefer Hasichos also contain letters that the Rebbe send to individuals and to world jewry.
